# Mongoid find by embedded document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have the following embedded structure

```
class CbAuthor
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many: cb_bylines

  field :name, type: String
end

class CbByline
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :cb_author
  has_many :cb_articles

  field :byline, type: String
end

class CbArticle
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :cb_byline
end
```

This is because there are many bylines or pseudonyms the authors publish under and that is will be attached to their analytics reports. So when I have a byline, how do I find the author? This will be necessary because They will have dashboards that should list all the articles they wrote under all their respective bylines.

I tried `CbAuthor.cb_bylines` but that gives me a no method error. or `CbAuthor.where(cb_bylines["byline"]: bylineInQuestion)` but that also gives errors.

Essentially the goal is to have one author name to find all his bylines and the articles associated with those bylines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`embeds_many :cb_bylines` is just a fancy way of saying "add an array of hashes called `cb_bylines`" (at least as far as storage is concerned). That means that your `CbAuthor`s look like this inside MongoDB:

```
{ 
  _id: '...',
  name: '...',
  cb_bylines: [
    { _id: '...', byline: '...' },
    ...
  ]
}
```

MongoDB will unroll the array for simple queries for you so you can simply look for `'cb_bylines.byline'` as though you were querying a hash inside the collection:

```
authors_by_lined_as_pancakes = CbAuthor.where('cb_bylines.byline' => 'Pancakes McGee')
```

or if you know there is just one:

```
pancakes_mcgee = CbAuthor.find_by('cb_bylines.byline' => 'Pancakes McGee')
```

Don't be afraid to bypass Rails and Mongoid to look at what your data really looks like inside MongoDB.